# How to correctly support multiple screen sizes

Tags: android, multiscreen

I have recycler view item with fixed height, so on 2560x1440 device it looks cool, but on 1280x720 it looks horible. I read google docs about that and they say just to use "wrap_content" , "match_parent" and use only dp and sp. As you can see below my cardView has 500dp height.I can't use "wrap_content" or "match_parent" because i need my buttom stay on center|bottom of cardview  Do i have to make different dimen values or something like that to fix this problem? 
If you need screens to see the problem, please leave comment, but i think you understand my problem

My item:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    >

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ticketQrCodeImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/ticketDescriptionLayout"
            />

        <include layout="@layout/view_underline"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ticketQrCodeImage"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/ticketDescriptionLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ticketMainImage"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_height="145dp"
                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ticketMainImage"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >
                <TextView
                    style="@style/TextViewBlackCustom"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/title_text_size"
                    android:id="@+id/ticketEventName"
                    android:text="Иван Дорн"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/TextViewGrayNotTransCustom"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:text="@string/tickets_date"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ticketDataText"
                        style="@style/TextViewBlackCustom"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:text="07.10 в 21:00"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/TextViewGrayNotTransCustom"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:text="@string/ticket_place"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ticketPlace"
                        style="@style/TextViewBlackCustom"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:text="Фан-зона"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/TextViewGrayNotTransCustom"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:text="@string/ticket_price"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ticketPriceText"
                        style="@style/TextViewBlackCustom"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:text="500 грн"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </RelativeLayout>


            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ticketReturnBtn"
        style="@style/ButtonCustomRed"
        android:text="@string/tickets_return_ticket_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center|bottom"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/cardView"

        />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

What i'm getting on low size devise:

[image]

What i need to get:

[image]

Comment: don't use fix height/widths like the documentation said. But if you really need that. then there are 2 ways to do it. either use dimens or use different directories like sw-720 for tablets etc.

Comment: @Umair yes,i know that this is bad to use fixed size, but i need it becouse i need that my button stay on center ander the card view

Comment: can you share the screenshot of your expected result ?

Comment: @Umair edited my question

Comment: see my answer below. This is fix the issue of overlapping fields, but I will recommend you to change your design for small screen sizes. Because even if you fix your problem this will mess up your view.

Comment: Use `ConstraintLayout`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `linearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` to avoid mixing up of items. But I would recommend you to use different design for small screens as it will mess up the whole design of you

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:id="@+id/cardView"

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="500dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ticketQrCodeImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ticketDescriptionLayout"
        />

    <include layout="@layout/view_underline"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ticketQrCodeImage"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ticketDescriptionLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ticketMainImage"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_height="145dp"
            />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ticketMainImage"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <TextView
                style="@style/TextViewBlackCustom"
                android:textSize="@dimen/title_text_size"
                android:id="@+id/ticketEventName"
                android:text="Иван Дорн"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
             <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
                <TextView
                    style="@style/TextViewGrayNotTransCustom"
                      android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="@string/tickets_date"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ticketDataText"
                    style="@style/TextViewBlackCustom"
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:text="07.10 в 21:00"
                     />

            </LinearLayout>
             <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp">
                <TextView
                    style="@style/TextViewGrayNotTransCustom"
                      android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"

                    android:text="@string/ticket_place"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ticketPlace"
                    style="@style/TextViewBlackCustom"
                      android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:text="Фан-зона"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >
                <TextView
                    style="@style/TextViewGrayNotTransCustom"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="@string/ticket_price"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ticketPriceText"
                    style="@style/TextViewBlackCustom"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:text="500 грн"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



<Button
    android:id="@+id/ticketReturnBtn"
    style="@style/ButtonCustomRed"
    android:text="@string/tickets_return_ticket_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="center|bottom"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/cardView"

    />
```

Comment: But it's a double work to create two layouts for one view

Comment: @Toper then you have to do what I have done in my answer use linearLayout. :)

Comment: But my problem not with images, my problem with incorrect displaying of CardView

Comment: your cardview is displaying correctly. the problem is screen size so either you make another layout for it or put a scrollview as a parent of cardview so that on small screen sizes it will scroll

Answer (score 0):

Use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)

Add this dependency in your `build.gradle` file

```
 compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

Here, copy the following code in your `layout.xml`

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ticketQrCodeImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/ticketDescriptionLayout" />

            <include
                layout="@layout/view_underline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ticketQrCodeImage" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/ticketDescriptionLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ticketMainImage"
                    android:layout_width="110dp"
                    android:layout_height="145dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ticketMainImage"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ticketEventName"
                        style="@style/TextViewBlackCustom"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Иван Дорн"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/title_text_size" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"

                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/TextViewGrayNotTransCustom"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:text="@string/tickets_date" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/ticketDataText"
                            style="@style/TextViewBlackCustom"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:text="07.10 в 21:00" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"

                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp">

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/TextViewGrayNotTransCustom"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:text="@string/ticket_place" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/ticketPlace"
                            style="@style/TextViewBlackCustom"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:text="Фан-зона" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"

                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp">

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/TextViewGrayNotTransCustom"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:text="@string/ticket_price" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/ticketPriceText"
                            style="@style/TextViewBlackCustom"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:text="500 грн" />

                    </RelativeLayout>


                </LinearLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ticketReturnBtn"
        style="@style/ButtonCustomRed"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="@string/tickets_return_ticket_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/cardView" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: but now my button is circumcised on half

Comment: set width to 0dp

Comment: on half of height

Comment: then use `wrap_content` in your height

Comment: Look at screen "What i need to get"

Comment: I thought you want custom height for your button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164828/discussion-between-dennis-and-toper).

Comment: any another suggestion?

Comment: i send email to you